# ZendFramework - only indexcontroller indexAction is working

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect

I have uploaded ZF on shared hosting but It's only `indexcontroller` and `indexAction` is working for rest it's showing "404 Page not Found".

Site is working fine on local server.

What can be the issue? Please help me.

Comment: Let me guess: your local server is hosted on Windows, but shared hosting is Unix one, right? )

Comment: I'd start with this, to narrow down where the problem could be: Put some debugging/logging statements in the controllers/actions that are not working and see if you are even getting to them.

Comment: e.g., have the controller write to a file in /tmp at the shared host and see if that file even gets written to.  If you don't have easy access to /tmp at the host, since your index controller is working, use it to echo the contents of the file.

Comment: Well, so I am bad at guessing: my point was about filenaming case inconsistency... can you check what paths are users redirected then?

Comment: Names are OK as I said working fine on local. I can't access any controller/action except index

Comment: I think the reason is that local `.htaccess` is not used in your shared hosting server. Therefore all the `/controller/action` paths result in 404 page. Could you try to literally put them into your request, like `something/index.php/some_controller/some_action`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mod_rewrite rules are not being applied. Mostly likely cause is that your web server is not setup to read .htaccess files (which is where the ZF rewrite rules are specified by default). Compare the setup for the Apache variable `AllowOverride` between your two environments.

Comment: One way to test this is to try to use http://myurl.com/index.php/about or whatever controller you want. If it works it is defenetly a rewriting issue as opposed to something wrong with your controllers, routes setup.

Answer (score 1):

my guess is .htaccess missing, or permissions on it, etc. resulting in a routing issue.  check the "non pretty" url to see but I'm guessing you'll reach the pages without a problem.